# Latin Regex with symbols

Tags: java, regex, split, symbols, latin

I need split a text and get only words, numbers and hyphenated composed-words. I need to get latin words also, then I used `\p{L}`, which gives me é, ú ü ã, and so forth. The example is:

```
String myText = "Some latin text with symbols, ? 987 (A la pointe sud-est de l'île se dresse la cathédrale Notre-Dame qui fut lors de son achèvement en 1330 l'une des plus grandes cathédrales d'occident) : ! @ # $ % ^& * ( ) + - _ #$% "  ' : ; > < / \  | ,  here some is wrong… * + () e -"

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{L}+(\\-\\p{L}+)*\\d]+");
String words[] = pattern.split( myText );
```

What is wrong with this regex? Why it matches symbols like `"("`, `"+"`, `"-"`, `"*"` and `"|"`?

Some of results are:

```
dresse     // OK
sud-est    // OK
occident)  // WRONG
987        // OK
()         // WRONG
(a         // WRONG
*          // WRONG
-          // WRONG
+          // WRONG
(          // WRONG
|          // WRONG
```

The regex explanation is:

```
[^\p{L}+(\-\p{L}+)*\d]+

 * Word separator will be:
 *     [^  ...  ]  No sequence in:
 *     \p{L}+        Any latin letter
 *     (\-\p{L}+)*   Optionally hyphenated
 *     \d            or numbers
 *     [ ... ]+      once or more.
```

Comment: Your understanding of your regex is incorrect. `[]` is character class and will match only a single character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If my understanding of your requirement is correct, this regex will match what you want:

```
"\\p{IsLatin}+(?:-\\p{IsLatin}+)*|\\d+"
```

It will match:

- A contiguous sequence of Unicode [Latin script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode) characters. I restrict it to Latin script, since `\p{L}` will match letter in **any** script. Change `\\p{IsLatin}` to `\\pL` if your version of Java doesn't support the syntax.
- Or several such sequences, hyphenated
- Or a contiguous sequence of decimal digits (0-9)

The regex above is to be used by calling `Pattern.compile`, and call `matcher(String input)` to obtain a `Matcher` object, and use a loop to find matches.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{IsLatin}+(?:-\\p{IsLatin}+)*|\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

If you want to allow words with apostrophe `'`:

```
"\\p{IsLatin}+(?:['\\-]\\p{IsLatin}+)*|\\d+"
```

I also escape `-` in the character class `['\\-]` just in case you want to add more. Actually `-` doesn't need escaping if it is the first or last in the character class, but I escape it anyway just to be safe.

Comment: It gives me an error: 
Unknown character property name {Latin} near index 12
[^\p{IsLatin}+(?:-\p{IsLatin}+)*|\d+]

Comment: @ManoelMerc: The code can be run on Java 7. If your version doesn't support it, then you can revert back to `\\p{L}`. And don't modify the regex!

Comment: Ok! We are almost there! I can get all words with no error! Thanks a lot! But the pipe symbol "|" is also matching as a word. I can't fix it! Here is my code:

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{L}+(?:-\\p{L}+)*|\\d+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( strText.toLowerCase() );

    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        
    while( matcher.find() )
    {
        words.add( matcher.group() );
    }
        
    return words.toArray(new String[words.size()]);

Comment: @ManoelMerc: `|` is never matched as a word. It is just alternation in regex.

Comment: Some of results are:

        "dresse"     // OK
        "sud-est"    // OK
        "|"          // WRONG

The compiller is thinking that pipe "|" is a word, and it isn't.

Comment: @ManoelMerc: Check again, it is likely that it is `l` (alphabet L) http://ideone.com/RAXXS6 http://ideone.com/HUDQTF

Comment: lol!! Oh my God! You r right! :) But we hava another problem: the word "l'île" is splitted in 2 words: "l" and "île"... Anyway! You was great! Thanx a lot, man!

Answer (score 2):

If the opening bracket of a character class is followed by a `^` then the characters listed inside the class are not allowed. So your regex allows **anything except** unicode letter,`+`,`(`,`-`,`)`,`*` and digit occurring one or more times.

Note that characters like `+`,`(`,`)`,`*` etc. don't have any special meaning inside a character class.

What pattern.split does is that it splits the string at patterns matching the regex. Your regex matches whitespace and hence split occurs at each occurrence of one or more whitespace. So result will be this.

For example consider this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a");
    for (String s : pattern.split("sda  a  f  g")) {
        System.out.println("==>"+s);
    }
```

Output will be

> ==>sd
>
> ==>
>
> ==>  f  g

Comment: Yes, it is anything except, because it is used to split the text.

See: pattern.split( myText );

Comment: @ManoelMerc I think you misunderstood pattern.split

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression set description with `[]` can contain only letters, classes (`\p{...}`), sequences (e.g. `a-z`) and the complement symbol (`^`).  You have to place the other magic characters you are using (`+*()`) *outside* the `[ ]` block.

Comment: I've change it to"\\(+|\\)+|\\*+|\\|+|\\-+|\\++|[^\\p{L}+(\\-\\p{L}+)*\\d]+", but it now matches empty strings and the pipe symbol "|" is matching anyway... :-(